# Neo4j warning when migrating to SDN6 and from neo4j 4 to 5

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How do I get rid of this warning?

> 19:14:07.370 [main] WARN
> org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.mapping.Neo4jPersistentEntity -
> The entity com.scl.attributefetcher.model.neo4j.AllianceContact is
> using a Long value for storing internally generated Neo4j ids. The
> Neo4j internal Long Ids are deprecated, please consider using an
> external ID generator.

```
public class AllianceContact {

    @RelationshipId
    private Long id;
    
    private User user;
    
    @TargetNode
    private AlliancePacket alliancePacket;
    
    private String role;

}
```

Comment: This article should be helpful: https://medium.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-and-spring-data-neo4j-a55a866df68c

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this warning is that internal integer IDs are deprecated in Neo4j 5 and are replaced with what's called "Element IDs", which are opaque strings (and still used for internal purposes).

I have not tried it, but maybe:

```java
    @RelationshipId
    private String id;
```

or:

```java
    @RelationshipId
    private ElementId id;
```

will work?